# Quarkus Mutiny + RESTEasy Reactive: What is actually transferred when returning a stream?

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-panache, mutiny

I am using **Quarkus + Mutiny + RESTEasy Reactive + ReactivePanacheMongoEntity**.

When calling my Reactive REST Api:

```
@GET
public Multi<Product> streamAllProducts(){
    return Product.streamAll();
}
```

... all I am getting as a result is

```
[
    Product<635917 edf0be2d3af200c0b9>,
    Product<635917 f3f0be2d3af200c0ba>,
    Product<635917 f3f0be2d3af200c0bb>
]
```

I was expecting the **whole objects**, like this

```
[
   {
     id: edf0be2d3af200c0b9
     name: Product 1
   },
   {
     id: f3f0be2d3af200c0ba
     name: Product 2
   },
   {
     id: f3f0be2d3af200c0bb
     name: Product 3
   }
]
```

When using the traditional (blocking) RESTEasy, I would get **the whole detailed objects**. So what is actually being transferred when using RESTEasy Reactive, and how do I use the results?

Comment: Are you using RESTEasy Reactive Jackson?

Comment: @geoand you solved my Problem . I was only using io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-reactive, but after reading your comment I found [this chapter](https://quarkus.io/guides/resteasy-reactive#json-serialisation) in the docs which explains it. I added Jackson and I now my response is correctly serialized. Just post an answer, I'll accept it 

Comment: Glad to hear it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jackson` is not being used, therefore proper JSON integration is not present in the REST stack.